# Solving partial differential equation in 2d with 3 boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Consider the following pde: $$-\Delta u =0$$ in $(0,\pi) \times (0,4)$ with boundary conditions:

$$u(0,y) = u(\pi,y) \ \text{for} \ y\in (0,4)$$

and $$u(x,0) = \cos x \sin x \ \text{for} \ x\in (0,\pi)$$
and $$u(x,4) = \cos x \sin x +4 \ \text{for} \ x\in (0,\pi)$$

I tried seperation of variables $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$

Inserting this yields two odes: $$g''(y)-cg(y)=0$$ and $$f''(x) + cf(x)=0$$ for some constant$c$

Consider the first ode. The characterstic polynomial is given by $\lambda^2=c$ Therefore there are 3 cases to consider:

$c=0: g(y)=  Ay+b$

$c>0: g(y)=  Ae^{\sqrt{c}y} + Be^{-\sqrt{c}y}$

$c<0: g(y)=  A\cos(\sqrt{-c} y) + B\sin(\sqrt{-c} y)$

How can I now use my boundary conditions. I only know $f(x)g(0) = f(x) \sin x \cos x$
I do not know how I can insert them?

Comment: You need to split the problem into two, the first problem in $u_{1}$ with boundary conditions $u_{1}(x,0) = \cos x \sin x$ and $u_{1}(x,4) = 0$ and another problem in $u_{2}$ with boundary conditions $u_{2}(x,0) = 0$ and $u_{2}(x,4) = \cos x \sin x + 4$. Then the final solution is a superposition of the two i.e $u = u_{1} + u_{2}$.

Comment: Why does this work here? How did you see that?

Comment: But about my seperation ansatz. Do I have to assume u=u_1+u_2 from the beginning?

Comment: First of all, you are missing a boundary condition in the $x$ direction, $u(0,y) = u(\pi,y)$ is not enough (or is it a typo?). Second, the solution I gave is just a superposition of solutions which satisfies the BCs. Yes, you need to split the problem into two pieces to begin as I stated before.

Comment: With the separation ansatz you get basis solutions. Any general solution will be a linear combination of basis solutions. The coefficients of the linear combinations are computed such that the linear combination satisfies the boundary conditions. Usually that is not possible with one product term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The periodic boundary condition tells you that the solution is $\pi$-periodic in $x$-direction, or at least can be interpreted as such if suitably extended outside the rectangle. This means that in that direction you get a Fourier series expansion
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{a_0(y)}2+\sum a_k(y)\cos(2kx)+b_k(y)\sin(2kx).
$$
This gives the same result as the separation approach, but starting from a different direction.

Comparing the conditions on the upper and lower boundaries gives $b_1(0)=b_1(4)=\frac12$, $a_0(4)=8$, all other coefficients are zero at $y=0$ and $y=4$. Further,
$$
-Δu(x,y)=-\frac{a_0''(y)}2+\sum_k[4k^2a_k(y)-a_k''(y)]\cos(2kx)+[4k^2b_k(y)-b_k''(y)]\sin(2kx).
$$
Now comparing coefficients and solving the simple DE gives
$$
a_0(y)=2y,\\
b_1(y)=\frac{\cosh(2(y-2))}{2\cosh(4)},
$$
all other coefficient functions being zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know where the fourier expansion comes from, but the rest is clear to me. What about the mssing condition for the boundary values. Why do I need one in addition?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no boundary condition missing. Any periodic function (if sufficiently regular) can be expanded as Fourier series. Often that also helps with the next steps.

Comment: Mattos made this comment. Why do the coefficients of the series only depend on y?

Comment: Because the function $u$ depends on $y$. The Fourier expansion is along lines $y=const.$ in $x$-direction, so for every $y$ the coefficients can change.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appricate your help:)